how to sort the application list
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 and when I press on the 'show apps' button the display shows me a alphabetically unsorted list of applications. Is there a way to sort this list?
I've tried the command:
gsettings set org.gnome.shell app-picker-layout "[]"
but it doesn't work.

There is a horizontal row of white dots at the bottom of the applications dashboard (Dash) that look like the small circles at the beginning of each line in bulleted lists. Clicking the first dot shows the first screen in the Dash, clicking the second dot shows the second screen in the Dash, and so on.
In Ubuntu 24.04 if you click an icon in the Dash you can drag this icon to the left side of the screen and hold it there. Then a small vertical animation that looks like a dock will appear. If you drag the icon into this small vertical dock it will move the icon into the previous screen. If you hold the icon in the small vertical dock for long enough it will cycle through the screens to the left. Similarly you can drag this icon to the right side of the screen and hold it there. If you drag the icon into the small vertical dock that pops up on the right side of the screen it will move the icon into the next screen or cycle through the screens to the right if you hold there for long enough.
You can move an icon inside the same screen simply by dragging it to its new position.
When you are done with this you will have all the icons arranged in alphabetical order. I don't arrange my app icons in alphabetic order in my Dash. Instead I dragged the icons of all the apps that I use every day into the first screen of the Dash. I then arranged them in order of how often I click them, with the icons of the most frequently used apps coming first in the sequence. This icon arrangement optimizes my workflow.

The user can also just press the Super key and start to type the name of the app required in the search box and the options based on how far into the name is typed are presented. I tend to use this now rather than the Dock (which I don't have presented on the screen)

The main reason I prefer to use my Dash is that my customized icon arrangement optimizes my workflow so that I can find the icon that I want to click quickly most of the time. That's because I know where it is. My Dash feels like an extension of my Dock in Ubuntu 24.04. What I scrapped instead was the Files file manager which is frequently unresponsive in my Ubuntu 24.04, so instead of Files I use Thunar now.

apologies - it wasn't a criticism (nor intended as an alternative answer) but another way to fire off an app which I have become accustomed to. If the Dash isn't present (as in my preferred use case), a double click on the Super key brings up the app list where the icon isn't present. The rest of your offering is spot on for the OP and I hope he accepts it
